# Calculated Column in Power BI - Last 7 Days

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in Power BI with the date and I am trying to create a calculated column that indicates if that date is within the last 7 days. I understand the syntax of the IF statement, but am having trouble with the actual time calculation. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your table looks like and what you want your calculated column to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DATEDIFF](https://dax.guide/datediff/) function to reliably determine the number of days (or weeks, or months, or years) between two dates:

```
IF(
    DATEDIFF(MyTable[MyDate], TODAY(), DAY) < 7,
    "Within last 7 days",
    "Not within last 7 days"
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great. If I wanted to do another one for the week before that (i.e. 2 weeks ago), how would that look?

Comment: You can combine multiple criteria like: `DATEDIFF(MyTable[MyDate], TODAY(), DAY) < 14 && DATEDIFF(MyTable[MyDate], TODAY(), DAY) >= 7`. But depending on what you want, it might be easier to use a [SWITCH](https://dax.guide/switch/) statement. For example: `SWITCH(DATEDIFF(MyTable[MyDate], TODAY(), WEEK), 0, "Within last 7 days", 1, "Within 7-14 days", 2, "Within 14-21 days", "More than 21 days ago)`